# Hibernate not fetching object from repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, repository

Im making a basic reset password functionality in my API but when i try to fetch the PasswordResetToken object from the repository hibernate doesnt fetch it and instead sends back null. Im 99% sure the PasswordResetToken that im trying to fetch is inside of the repository because i did some system.out.println's and it shows the PasswordResetToken is in there with the matching token it just doesnt send anything back.

heres the email varification and token creation

```
@PostMapping("/resetPassword")
    public String resetPassword(@RequestBody PasswordModel passwordModel, HttpServletRequest request) {
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(passwordModel.getEmail());
        String url = "";
        if(user!=null) {
            String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            userService.createPasswordResetTokenForUser(user, token);
            url = passwordResetTokenMail(user, applicationUrl(request), token);
        }
        return url;
    }
```

service methods that go along with it

```
    @Override
    public User findUserByEmail(String email) {
        
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    @Override
    public void createPasswordResetTokenForUser(User user, String token) {
        PasswordResetToken passwordResetToken
                = new PasswordResetToken(user, token);
        passwordResetTokenRepo.save(passwordResetToken);
    }
```

save new password functionality where the issue happens

```
    @PostMapping("/savePassword")
    public String savePassword(@RequestParam("token") String token,
                               @RequestBody PasswordModel passwordModel) {
        String result = userService.validatePasswordResetToken(token);
        if(!result.equalsIgnoreCase("valid")) {
            return "Invalid token";
        }
        Optional<User> userOptional = userService.getUserByPasswordResetToken(token);
        if(userOptional.isPresent()) {
            userService.changePassword(userOptional.get(), passwordModel.getNewPassword());
            return "Password has been updated";
        } else {
            return "Invalid token";
        }
    }
```

service methods

```
    @Override
    public String validatePasswordResetToken(String token) {
        PasswordResetToken passwordResetToken
                = passwordResetTokenRepo.findByToken(token);
        if(passwordResetToken == null) {
            return "invalid";
        }

        User user = passwordResetToken.getUser();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        if((passwordResetToken.getExpirationTime().getTime())
                - cal.getTime().getTime() <=0) {
            passwordResetTokenRepo.delete(passwordResetToken);
            return "expired";
        }

        return "valid";
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> getUserByPasswordResetToken(String token) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(passwordResetTokenRepo.findByToken(token).getUser());
    }

    @Override
    public void changePassword(User user, String newPassword) {
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(newPassword));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

and finally the repository

```
@Repository
public interface PasswordResetTokenRepo extends JpaRepository<PasswordResetToken, Long> {
    PasswordResetToken findByToken(String token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out incase anyone runs into the same issue. I was using postman on the client side and for some reason when I was copying the URL and pasting it into postman it was adding a space after the url so the token ended up being token=xyz with a space after instead of just token xyz. That’s why it looked like the token was there in the repo because you couldn’t tell there was a space after it.